# If multiplication operator is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, compact-operators

I have a question: we have a multiplication operator $M:C[0,1]\rightarrow L^1[0,1]$ which looks like this: $x(t)\rightarrow tx(t)$ . I need to know whether this operator is compact or not and why?  My expirements with Riess criterion didn't give any answers to me. Hope you will help me with it.

Comment: What is $L[0,1]$?

Comment: I have fixed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Fix an $\epsilon$ for which $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Consider the subspace
$$
S = \{f : f(x) = 0 \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq \epsilon\} \subset C[0,1].
$$
Note that $S$ is an invariant subspace of $M$, so that $M|_{S} : S \to S$ where $M|_{S}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $S$.  Note that $M|_{S}$ is invertible and therefore cannot be compact.

It follows that $M$ cannot be compact.

Comment: Being invertible then it is not compact, why?

Comment: As i understand, it is because its image is infinite dimensional

Comment: Am i right, that in your answer your mean that we can fix $C$, for example 0.1. Then we consider continious functions $f(x)=0$ if $x=[0,0.1]$ . And then we can take a reverse operator $1/x$ for which we excluded 0 from our possible values for x. But $xf(x)$ is infinite dimensional if $f(x)$ have properties named above. Therefore, our operator can't be compact.

Comment: The only thing that is a bit unclear to me is why S is an invariant subspace?

Comment: If f is zero over some interval, then Mf also has to be zero over this interval

Comment: All right, now i get it. Thank you very much)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant $C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$.  Let $T$ be the operator of multiplication by $g(t) = \min(2t, 1/t)$.  Then $MT$ is the identity on the subspace $V$ of
$C[0,1]$ consisting of functions that are $0$ on $[0,1/2]$.  That being an infinite-dimensional subspace, $MT$ can't be compact, and therefore $T$ can't be compact.

Comment: No, the original problem clearly says that its image lies in $L[0,1]$.

Comment: Space of functions which can be integrated being raised to the first power. I am sorry, probably i had to write this way: $L^1[0,1]$. I wiil change my question now

Answer (score 0):

$\{t\exp(2i\pi n t)\}_{n\ge 0}$ doesn't have any convergent subsequence in $L^1[0,1]$.

For a continuous linear map $M:X\to Y$ on Banach spaces, the definition of  compact is that $M$ sends the unit ball of $X$ to a subset of $Y$ whose closure is compact (for example this is the case with $f:\ell^1\to \ell^1, f(x)_j = \frac{x_j}{j+1}$)

Comment: I am not sure if we can use complex number in functions based on $[0,1]$

Comment: $t\cos(2\pi n t)$ has no convergent subsequence in $\ell^1$ (the Fourier coefficients of this sequence would converge in $\ell^\infty$)

Comment: That looks better to me. But as far as i remember, definition of compactness for operator is that it sends bounded set from $X$ to a precompact set of $Y$.

Comment: Yes I was too much thinking to the convergent subsequence, we don't care if the limit is in the image or not. Looking at all the bounded sets is the same as looking only at the unit ball. Compact operator = we can approach it (in operator norm) with a sequence of matrices.

Comment: Moreover, i have another type of functional space. But i am not sure if $L^1[0,1]$ and $l^1[0,1]$ differ a lot